# How can I implement a webhook C# as a Receiver backend and .net core as publisher?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

I have this requirement to use webhook.

I am new to this concept.

I am trying to implement this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers

Currently I have:

```
using JahezWebhookAPI.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JahezWebhookAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class JahezSalesOrderHandler : ControllerBase,  IWebHookHandler
    { 
        public int Order => 1;

        public string Receiver => "JAHEZ";

        public List<JahezSalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; set; }

        [Route("Create")]
        [HttpPost]       
        public Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
        {

            CustomNotifications notifications = context.GetDataOrDefault<CustomNotifications>();
            foreach (var notification in notifications.Notifications)
            {
                foreach(var note in notification)
                {
                  //my logic goes here
                }
            }
            return Task.FromResult(true);
            
        }
    }
}
```

I have two questions,

first one, how my client can pass the  `WebHookHandlerContext`?

second how do I return OK from task result?

Comment: Why exactly do you serialize and then deserialize again? (Probably unrelated)

Comment: _"how do I return OK"_ - I'd also return "201 - Created" from a POST.

Comment: Why do you want this? Why not just `return Ok();`? You gain *nothing* by returning `Task.FromResult(true);`. The entire method will be executed synchronously until the `return` clause.  In any case, web requests are processed by separate pooled threads so there's no point in starting *another* thread to do CPU-intensive work "in the background".

Comment: Serializing something only to *deserialize* it back is an extremely expensive way to map data, especially since the attribute names must match exactly. Why not use the data you already have? Or use AutoMapper to map to a DTO type by name? Or use a LINQ Select to map one type to another?

Comment: @PeterBruins what would be the point of it? There's nothing asynchronous in this method so there's no need to return any task.

Comment: ^^ But before making this sync, check if `SalesOrders` provides async API. You _might_ want to use it.

Comment: I want to implement a web hook and create a publisher to subscribe to my webjook. We can return 201 as created.  How can I do that asynchronous